# Deleting Channel Entries in the Frontend

Tags: channel-entries

Deleting channel entries is pretty straightforward in the EE Control Panel.

But how do I do it via the frontend? Do I need to use the Channel Form tag?

Or is there a native EE tag specifically for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built in method for this, not even with channel forms to my understanding.

My first thought was to have a template such as  `/delete/{entry_id}/` where `{entry_id}` is what you wanted to remove. Of course, that template would need to check you had the correct permissions.

That template would have an `{exp:query}` module which would run the SQL to delete the entry. **But that isn't possible** because `{exp:query}` only allows for `SELECT` statements.

The alternative is to write a simple plugin `{exp:delete entry_id="segment_1"}` which would run that SQL for you.

**But I don't think any of this is a good idea.** It feels like it could open up security problems.

The control panel's deleting is based on permissions and is well rounded; a front-end solution is likely to fall short.

Comment: Your first thought is exactly what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, this feature is necessary. I will have to keep in mind the security problem though. Maybe check if the user trying to delete is the author of the entry.